# Prove that the product of two lines equations is hyperbola

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

How should I prove that the product of two line equations, which is not equal to 0, is hyperbola?

I guess I can use $s,Δ,δ$ invariants, but are there no other elegant and easier to count options?

And if no, is the invariants method the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

Let L1=0 and L2=0 be two nonparallel lines then L1 L2=c means (L1+L2)^2 -(L1-L2)^2=4c, which is the most general equation of a hyperbola.